# get History version from firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have site that deployed on firebase hosting [site](https://sarafe-testing.web.app/)
on the site I wrote `Version 3` but instead of that I want to show the deployment / release version like `e925c5` that writen on the history version.

can I get history version with Rest API.? or can I define it before deployed.?
thank you

## Update

I try with reading [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/sites.versions/list) and working with it, but still stuck with the authentication method,

Simple function is this, but always returned 403 response, already try with `getGlobalDefaultAccount.login()` and `getGlobalDefaultAccount.getAccessToken()` and `getGlobalDefaultAccount()` still not working,

```
const requireAuth = require('firebase-tools/lib/requireAuth')
const getGlobalDefaultAccount = require('firebase-tools/lib/auth')
const api = require('firebase-tools/lib/api')

const site = 'sarafe-testing'
requireAuth(getGlobalDefaultAccount.getAccessToken(), ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']).then(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await api.request('GET', `/v1beta1/sites/${site}/releases`, { auth: true, origin: api.hostingApiOrigin })
    console.log(response)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message)
  }
})
```

[Full version](https://gist.github.com/puf/e00c34dd82b35c56e91adbc3a9b1c412)

For now I just created table that hold version code (manuali update from firebase page) and make API to get the version, but this not a valid solution because is only show the latest version, some other people just open the webpage without refresh / clear cache so that one is still using the old version of webpage with latest version written,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a REST API that allows you to manage versions and releases for Firebase Hosting, and it has a method to get a [list of versions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/sites.versions/list) for the site. I recommend checking out its [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) and reporting back if you get stuck while implementing the code.

Comment: oh yes forgot to mention that I already try the Firebase Hosting documentation, but Getting stuck with the code and get CORS / Auth error for me, any example available.?

Comment: Here's a script I wrote a while ago: https://gist.github.com/puf/e00c34dd82b35c56e91adbc3a9b1c412 But if you're having trouble making code work, edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is much more likely that somebody can help with that.

Comment: thank you, but I still stuck with same problem, the code is actualy same just calling url for getting the version, my problem is if I use webapp, it's getting cors error and Auth, if using nodejs is still auth error. the 'getGlobalDefaultAccount' from the source you give me is not a function, is have 3 exported method login, getAccessToken, logout, after some experiment still not working it just login multiple time, but the request still return with 403